# How to use Regex to break line after comma

Tags: javascript

I need to break line after comma using regex(another method is welcome too)

```
function breakLineAfterComma(){
    let Text = "This is an Example. Break Line Here"
    Text.replace('regex here')
    return Text;
}
```

Comment: Please fix the question, you said you want to break after the comma but you have mentioned pull stop in the question .?

Comment: I don't see a comma. Perhaps you meant a period?

Comment: Are you looking for `return Text.replaceAll(".", ".\n");`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to replace all periods and a space with a newline:

```js
function breakLineAfterComma(){
    let Text = "This is an Example. Break Line Here. Break Line Here"
    return Text.replace(/\. /g, "\n");
}

console.log(breakLineAfterComma())
```

You can also use [`String.replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll):

```js
function breakLineAfterComma(){
    let Text = "This is an Example. Break Line Here. Break Line Here"
    return Text.replaceAll(". ", "\n");
}

console.log(breakLineAfterComma())
```

Answer (score 0):

it's possible to use regex and replace "." with a break.

here is the reusable function example

```
function breakLineAfterComma(text){
    return text.replace(/\./g, '\n');
}

const content = "This is an Example. Break Line Here"
const a = breakLineAfterComma(content);
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function splitText(text){
  text = "This is an Example. Break Line Here";
  return text.split('. ').join('.\n');
// This is an Example. 
// Break Line Here
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.